# Coupled equations to find the best parameter

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have a coupled equation I would like to plot them with different values of the parameter $m$ to find for which $m$ it has my favorite answer:

```
Derivative[1][y][t] + 3*a*((Derivative[1][x][t]*y[t])/x[t]) = 9*b*((Derivative[1][x][t]^2*y[t]^m)/x[t]^2); 
Derivative[1][x][t]^2 = (y[t] + f)*x[t]^2 - 1;
```

$a$, $b$ and $f$ are 1.3, 0.3 and 0.7 respectively.

Comment: "for which m it has my favorite answer" is mathematically imprecise!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Note that your equations should be defined using `==` (Equal) and not `=` (Set).

Comment: You need some initial conditions `x[0],x'[0]`

Comment: x[0]=0 and x'[0]=0 but it is nearly zero imagine  0.000000000000001

Comment: m should be 0, 1/2,1/3,1/4,1,2 ....

Comment: Derivative[1][y][t] + 3*a*((Derivative[1][x][t]*y[t])/x[t]) = 9*b*((Derivative[1][x][t]^2*y[t]^m)/x[t]^2)==0; 
Derivative[1][x][t]^2 = (y[t] + f)*x[t]^2 - 1;

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html) and [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

a = 13/10; b = 3/10; f = 7/10;

eqns = {y'[t] + 3*a*((x'[t]*y[t])/x[t]) ==
    9*b*((x'[t]^2*y[t]^m)/x[t]^2),
   x'[t]^2 == (y[t] + f)*x[t]^2 - 1,
   x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0};

sol = ParametricNDSolve[eqns, {x, y}, {t, 0, 1},
   {m, x0, y0}, WorkingPrecision -> 15];

Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[{x[m, x0, y0][t], y[m, x0, y0][t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 1}],
 {{m, 1}, -4, 4, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{x0, 1}, 1, 5, 0.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{y0, 1}, 0, 1.5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]